# Environment-specific ebextensions on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deploy the same application to two different environments `app-web` and `app-worker`. The configuration of these environments differs slightly (e.g. they run different processes) so some different `.ebextensions` will be required for each. Is there a way to specify that a certain config file should only be run for a certain environment?

Here's the config file that needs to be set for the worker environment only:

```
packages:
  yum:
    monit: []

files:
  "/etc/monit.d/resque_worker":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      check process resque_worker_QUEUE
        with pidfile /var/app/resque_worker_QUEUE.pid
        start program = "/bin/sh -l -c 'cd /var/app/current; nohup rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=/var/app/resque_worker_QUEUE.pid >> log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log 2>&1'" as uid webapp and gid webapp
        stop program = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /var/app/current && kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/resque_worker_QUEUE.pid) && rm -f /var/app/resque_worker_QUEUE.pid; exit 0;'"
        if totalmem is greater than 300 MB for 10 cycles then restart  # eating up memory?
        group resque_workers

commands:
  remove_bak:
    command: "rm /etc/monit.d/resque_worker.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true

service:
  sysvinit:
    monit:
      ensureRunning: true
      enabled: true
```

I know I can test for the presence of an environmental variable to stop commands from running with the `commands/test`, but I'm not sure what to do with the rest.

Comment: Won't environment vars serve your needs?

Comment: I've got packages, services, files, and commands directives that need to run.  The commands directives can be toggled with an environmental variable using `test`, but I'm not sure how to handle the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as far as I can tell, there's no way to do this at this time, which is pretty obnoxious... I ended up writing a [script which conditionally enables worker extensions for deploys](https://gist.github.com/fny/975caff90a945a05172b).

Basically during a worker deploy, the script enables certain files by changing the extension from `worker-config` to `config`, create a temporary commit, deploy, then reset the commit.